# pytest, user input and exception

Tags: python, pytest

I'm very new to unit testing so sorry for my newbie question.
I've written a small class with one instance attribute, "name".

The goal here is to ask the user for input if no "name" parameter is passed when the class is instantianted, and to verify if the name is formatted as expected.

Here is the class definition:

```py
class Customer:
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name.upper()

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        while True:
            try:
                if not value:
                    value = str(input("Please enter the customer's name: "))
                else:
                    print("Customer name found: {}".format(value))
                if not bool(re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9 _-]*$", value)) or value == "":
                    raise (ValueError)
            except ValueError:
                print("Invalid customer name.")
                value = None
                continue
            break
        self._name = value
```

It's working as expected:

```py
>>> customer = Customer()
Please enter the customer's name: &&invalid
Invalid customer name.
Please enter the customer's name: valid
>>> customer.name
'VALID'
>>>
```

My test file is as follows:

```py
import script
import pytest


class TestCustomer:
    def setup_method(self):
        self.customer = script.Customer("validname")

    def teardown_method(self):
        self.customer = ""

    def test_valid_name(self):
        self.customer.name = "validname"
        assert self.customer.name == "VALIDNAME"

    def test_invalid_name(self):
        with pytest.raises(ValueError):
            self.customer.name = "&invalidname&"
```

However, when I'm trying to test this with pytest, this happens:

```py
========================================================================= FAILURES =========================================================================
______________________________________________________________ TestCustomer.test_invalid_name ______________________________________________________________

self = <test_script.TestCustomer object at 0x7f1ad68f39a0>

    def test_invalid_name(self):
        with pytest.raises(ValueError):
>           self.customer.name = "&invalidname&"

test_script.py:18: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
script.py:17: in name
    value = str(input("Please enter the customer's name: "))
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <_pytest.capture.DontReadFromInput object at 0x7f1ad693d2e0>, args = ()

    def read(self, *args):
>       raise IOError(
            "pytest: reading from stdin while output is captured!  Consider using `-s`."
        )
E       OSError: pytest: reading from stdin while output is captured!  Consider using `-s`.

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/_pytest/capture.py:732: OSError
------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout setup -------------------------------------------------------------------
Customer name found: validname
------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------
Customer name found: &invalidname&
Invalid customer name.
Please enter the customer's name: 
================================================================= short test summary info ==================================================================
FAILED test_script.py::TestCustomer::test_invalid_name - OSError: pytest: reading from stdin while output is captured!  Consider using `-s`.
=============================================================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.07s ================================================================
```

When I'm using the -s option, and enter a valid name, the exception is not raised:

```py
test_script.py Customer name found: validname
Customer name found: validname
.Customer name found: validname
Customer name found: &invalidname&
Invalid customer name.
Please enter the customer's name: test
F

========================================================================= FAILURES =========================================================================
______________________________________________________________ TestCustomer.test_invalid_name ______________________________________________________________

self = <test_script.TestCustomer object at 0x7f4f2e1f6640>

    def test_invalid_name(self):
        with pytest.raises(ValueError):
>           self.customer.name = "&invalidname&"
E           Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'ValueError'>

test_script.py:18: Failed
================================================================= short test summary info ==================================================================
FAILED test_script.py::TestCustomer::test_invalid_name - Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'ValueError'>
=============================================================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 1.96s ================================================================
```

I can't get my head around this ...
Any help would be very appreciated :).